# How can I create an IDynamicDisplay obj in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

I am trying to draw a text glyph on the map and all the tutorials say I need a IDynamicDisplay, but I don't know how to get at one.  Thanks in advance. ; ) 
edit: C# VS2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wire up an event handler

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IDynamicMapEvents_Event dynamicMapEvents = dynamicMap as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IDynamicMapEvents_Event;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveViewEvents_Event avEvents = activeView as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveViewEvents_Event;
avEvents.AfterDraw += new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveViewEvents_AfterDrawEventHandler(avEvents_AfterDraw);
dynamicMapEvents.AfterDynamicDraw += new IDynamicMapEvents_AfterDynamicDrawEventHandler(dynamicMapEvents_AfterDynamicDraw);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set IDynamicMap::DynamicMapEnabled property from Map object to true.

```
IDynamicMap pDynamicMap = pMap as IDynamicMap;
pDynamicMap.DynamicMapEnabled = true
```

Then, there are two ways to get DynamicDisplay object. One is creating custom Layer with implement IDynamicLayer interface. Second one is hooking IDynamicMapEvents::BeforeDynamicDraw event or IDynamicMapEvents::AfterDynamicDraw event. I hope this best practice help you.

[Best practices for using dynamic display](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000122000000)